Decomposition of a family of positive semi-definite matrices
This question is a generalization of this  simple fact:

Any positive semi-definite matrix $M$ is (non-uniquely) of the form $M=N^T N$ for some real matrix $N$.

The question is:
If $f:\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathrm{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ is a $C^\infty$-function (here $\mathrm{Mat}_{n\times n}=\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ is the space of $n\times n$-matrices) such that $f(x)$ is a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^k$, can we always find a $C^\infty$-function $g: \mathbb{R}^k\to\mathrm{Mat}_{m\times n}(\mathbb R)$ such that $f(x)=g(x)^Tg(x)$ $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^k$?
[My motivation was to get a simple proof of the existence of solutions of some PDEs; the question is much more elementary than the motivation, yet I was not able to solve it.]
edit: $m$ can be taken as large as needed. Sometimes it has to be larger than $n$, as the example
$$
x^2+y^2 =
\begin{pmatrix}
x & y
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ y
\end{pmatrix}
$$
shows (with $n=1$ and $m=2$).

$f:\mathbb R^2\to \operatorname{Mat}_{1\times 1}(\mathbb R),; (x,y)\mapsto x^2+y^2$ seems to be a counterexample.

@flowing no it's not, we can take $g(x,y)=(x,y)^T$

We can simply take $g(x) = \sqrt{f(x)}$ if $f(x)$ is always positive definite, but where $f(x)$ changes rank, I suspect there is a possibility that $g$ fails to be $C^\infty$.

Are you placing any restriction on $m$ here, or is the idea to show that a sufficiently large $m$ can always be chosen (as is the case with your above comment)?

@BenGrossmann no restriction on $m$ in principle (though one can ask about it). $\sqrt{f}$ indeed doesn't have to be smooth, as the 1st comment shows (with $1\times1$-matrices).

The mathoverflow post (MO/questions/106069) says that even $(k,n)=(1,1)$ case is false, which implies all cases of $(k,n)$ are false. But I'm not very sure since the counter-example of $(1,1)$ case is not published (see that MO post) and some people still consider it as an open problem.

@PureRun89 Thanks! So this looks more complicated than what I imagined ...

@PureRun89 Actually, the pdf linked there https://www.cmls.polytechnique.fr/perso/bony/BBCP_jfa.pdf gives a negative answer for $(k,n)=(4,1)$ with a complete proof (based on a result of Hilbert for polynomials).
